# Building hadoop 2.5.1 with windows sdk 7 failed

Tags: winapi, hadoop

By the way, I have followed the instructions specified in BUILDING.txt in hadoop source folder , I'm a newbie to win sdk, any ideas are appreciated.

---

Project "E:\HD\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\nat
ive\native.sln" on node 1 (default targets).

ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Win32".
Project "E:\HD\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln" (1) is building "E:\HD\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\Windows7.1SDK\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Windows7.1SDK.targets(20,5): 
**error : You are attempting to build an AMD64 application from an x86 environment. If using the Windows 7.1 SDK, type setenv /x64 [E:\HD\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj]**
Done Building Project "E:\HD\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "E:\HD\hadoop-2.5.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Answer (score 1):

just set this variable beforehand

```
set TARGET_CPU=amd64
```

Comment: I have solved this question through this link http://www.cnblogs.com/smartbooks/p/3694760.html, I'm sorry this is  a Chinese link.